# Multiple webservice Making UI unresponsive

Tags: ios

The problem is that I am calling multiple webservices on my homepage and the webservice is returning me the images and text from the server. During this process the UI become fully unresponsive for say 1-2 minutes which is looking very bad as I cant do anything. I heard about dispatch and tried to implement it but I dont get any results.May be I am doing something wrong.

What I want now that I want to that I want to run this process in background So that a user can interact with the UI during the fetching operation from the server. I am implementing my code just tell me where to use dispatch.

```
-(void)WebserviceHomeSlider{
if([AppDelegate appDelegate].isCheckConnection){

    //Internet connection not available. Please try again.
    UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internate error" message:@"Internet connection not available. Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
    return;
}else {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:ServiceUrl@"fpMainBanner" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id responseObject)
     {
         //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

         arrSlider = [responseObject objectWithJSONSafeObjects];
         [_slideshow setTransitionType:KASlideShowTransitionSlide];
         _slideshow.gestureRecognizers = nil;
         [_slideshow addGesture:KASlideShowGestureSwipe];
         //         [_slideshow addImagesFromResources:[self getImages]]; // Add
         //         [_slideshow addTextFromResources:[self getText]];
         // [slideShow subtextWithImages:[self getsubText]];


         [_slideshow addImagesFromResources:[self getImages] stringArray:[self getText] stringsubArray:[self getsubText]];

     }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];



}
```

}

Just tell me where to use dispatch or edit my code using dispatch if possible. I have gone through some examples but still my concept is not clear. Which dispatch method id best (DEFAULT or BACKGROUND). I will be very thankful to You.

This is the code you are looking for . Just tell me where to edit it using dispatch

```
-(NSArray *)getText{
NSMutableArray *textArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



for(int i=0; i<[arrSlider count];i++)
{


    texxt=[[arrSlider objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"title" ];
    [textArr addObject:[texxt uppercaseString]];


}


return textArr;
```

}

-(NSArray *)getsubText{
    NSMutableArray *subtext = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
for(int i=0; i<[arrSlider count];i++)
{


    subbtext=[[arrSlider objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"tagline_value" ];
    if(i==8)
    {
        subbtext=@"MAKE YOURSELF STAND OUT GET YOUR FREE CARDS!";


    }
    NSLog(@"subtext is,,.,.,,.,%@.%@",@"k",subbtext);


    [subtext addObject:[subbtext uppercaseString]];



}


return subtext;
```

}

-(NSArray *)getImages
{
    NSMutableArray *mArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
for(int i=0; i<[arrSlider count];i++)
{
    pathh=[[arrSlider objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"filepath" ];

    NSString *newString = [pathh stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];



    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:newString];


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(320, 158);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
    [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //        [whotshotimgview setImage:image];
    [mArr addObject: img];

}


return mArr;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 [_slideshow addImagesFromResources:[self getImages] stringArray:[self getText] stringsubArray:[self getsubText]];
```

The problem here is that you didn't showed implementation of addImagesFromResources method. You probably have to implement GCD in this method because i guess you are fetching images and setting on UI by this your main thread is getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `UIView` from thread other than the main which causes the UI unresponsiveness.

Please use this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [_slideshow setTransitionType:KASlideShowTransitionSlide];
         _slideshow.gestureRecognizers = nil;
         [_slideshow addGesture:KASlideShowGestureSwipe];
         //         [_slideshow addImagesFromResources:[self getImages]]; // Add
         //         [_slideshow addTextFromResources:[self getText]];
         // [slideShow subtextWithImages:[self getsubText]];


         [_slideshow addImagesFromResources:[self getImages] stringArray:[self getText] stringsubArray:[self getsubText]];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that your UI hangs due to downloading of image. 
So you should use SDWebImage library that can help you to cache image and also prevent the UI getting hang.
 Using SDWebImage you can show the loader for the time the image is not loaded and it will cache the image. 
So from next time no image will be downloaded and also the UI will not hang. 
The link for complete reference to SDWebImage is :
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

This block blocking your main UI to perform tasks so update this block as follow,

```
for(int i=0; i<[arrSlider count];i++)
    {
        pathh=[[arrSlider objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"filepath" ];

        NSString *newString = [pathh stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];


        dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
            dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
                NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:newString];


                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

                UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(320, 158);
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
                [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
                UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                //        [whotshotimgview setImage:image];
                [mArr addObject: img];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // If you want to refresh your UI simultaniously, you can write statement for that i.e
                    // yourImageView.image = img;
                    // Otherwise remove this queue

                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code. Right now I m ussing KASlidershow as third party tool to display images with text and subtext. After trying your code KAslider is not showing any images. Its showing the text and subtext part. All the text and subtext is showing at a time all together at one place which is not looking good.

Comment: It is because the images are loading in another thread and you are populating your slider right after getting the data. You have to wait untill all images loaded into the array or there must be a delegate method of slider which is taking the data from your datasource. like we have cellforrow of uitableview.

Comment: You can also implement this protocol to use the slideshow in a more memory efficient way.

- (UIImage *)slideShow:(KASlideShow *)slideShow imageForPosition:(KASlideShowPosition)position
{
}

Answer (score 0):

The main thread should never be used for long processing. Its there for the UI.

AFNetworking provides asynchronous functionality for downloading files. You should also be careful of thrashing the network layer with too many simulatanous downloads. I think 4 or 5 is the max the last time I tested.

So the flow of execution should be as follows.

The controller sets up the slideshow, sends the downloading of the images to a background thread(automatically handled by AFNetworking), passing a completion block to it. In this completion block you need to dispatch the work back to the main thread using GCD, dispatch_async to dispatch_get_get_main_queue

Keep your main thread's run loop available for user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the images are loading in another thread and you are populating your slider right after getting the data.

It is better to implement this protocol method of KASlidershow to use the slideshow in a more memory efficient way.

- (UIImage *)slideShow:(KASlideShow *)slideShow imageForPosition:(KASlideShowPosition)position
  {
  pathh=[[arrSlider objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"filepath" ];

  ```
  NSString *newString = [pathh stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];


  dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
      dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
          NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:newString];


          NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

          UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

          CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(320, 158);
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
          [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
          UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
          //        [whotshotimgview setImage:image];
          [mArr addObject: img];

          return img;
      });
  ```

  }

**i didn't try the code but i hope it will work with little changes in variable names. Good luck**

Comment: I tried your code but in this case I am getting img always nil. I got the imagepath converted that path into nsurl but after this when I am converting this into Nsdata , Nsdata is always coming nil. I also copied the image url into the broswer and It exist. I am copying the path here                             http://www.musicians4rent.com/dev/sites/default/files/imagecache/fp_main_banner_slider/dummy1.1.jpg

Comment: You have to load all of your images in to an array at the time when your view load. Load them in asynchronous way by making dispatch queue. When all images loaded in to the array, call start function of your slider.